# Can we replace the $B$ to $A$ in this proposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am working through Atiyah's Commutative algebra and am having question with the following proposition:

> $\text{Page 63:}$
>
> *Proposition 5.15.* Let $A$ $\subseteq$ $B$ be integral domains, $A$ integrally closed, and
> let $x$ $\in$ $B$ be integral over an ideal $a$ of $A$. Then $x$ is algebraic over the field of
> fractions $K$ of $A$, and if its minimal polynomial over $K$ is $t^n+a_1t^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n$, then $a_1,\ldots, a_n$ lie in $r(a)$.

1.Can we replace the $x$ $\in$ $B$ to $x$ $\in$ $A$ in this proposition? Because $A$ integrally closed.

2.Why we need the polynomial be the minimal polynomial?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. is trivial, since if $x\in A$ then $x\in B$.

Comment: Perhaps (1) is "in the proof of this proposition, can we reduce to showing it for $x \in A$?". If that's the case, I don't see how. As for (2), take the minimal polynomial and multiply it by $(t - b)$ where $b \in B \setminus A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1, $A$ is integrally closed means $A$ is closed in the field of fractions, not in $B$.

2, Because conjugate elements are other roots of the minimal polynomial of $x$. See: [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_element_%28field_theory%29)